# How to use laravel-bladet raits inside Javascript's script

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have laravel traits that convert numbers to money-currency format.
If I want to use it on blade template I only call it like

```
<td class="text-center"> @money($repayment->admnin) </td>
```

My problem is, I want to use it inside the  tag, how do I suppose to use that @money traits?

here's my code example

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: `${url}/${due_date}`,
    }).done((data) => {
        let paymentTotal = 10000;
        let { totalInterest, totalPrincipal, paymentTotal,
            due_date, loanNumber, borrowerFullname } = data;
            $('#simulation-table').show();
            $('#totalbayar').append(
                // I want to use that @money here, I tried like this below
                `@money(${paymentTotal})`
            )
    }).fail((err) => {
        console.log(err, 'error coy');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can assign an id to `<td>` like

```
<td id="xyz" class="text-center"> @money($repayment->admnin) </td>
```

and in Ajax you can get the value by using jquery or javascript :

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: `${url}/${due_date}`,
}).done((data) => {
    let paymentTotal = 10000;

    let pay = $('xyz').val() // for jquery
    let pay = document.getElementById("xyz").value // for javascript

    let { totalInterest, totalPrincipal, paymentTotal,
        due_date, loanNumber, borrowerFullname } = data;
        $('#simulation-table').show();
        // and you can use the value like this 
        $('#totalbayar').append(pay))

}).fail((err) => {
    console.log(err, 'error coy');
});
```